# Add datas with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hello I want to create or update datas with EF6 in a transaction.
In a method, I want to create a doc model like this :

```
docCible = new SCR_MDL_DOC();
docCible = transposition.TransposeObject(docSrc, docCible);
docCible.DC_OCC = DateTime.Now;
docCible.ID_UTIL_CREAT = IdUtilisateur;
docCible.NO_SEQ_GABAR_MDL_DOC = gabaritCible.NO_SEQ_GABAR_MDL_DOC;

context.SCR_MDL_DOC.Add(docCible);
context.SaveChanges();

docCible.NO_SEQ_MDL_DOC = docCible.NO_SEQ_MDL_DOC;
```

I pass my context as a param of my save method.

The problem is that, when I do my saveChanges, I would like to get the ID of my new record.
But the ID is still 0.
I Thought that I could get the new ID, even if my transaction is not yet commited...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using database-generated IDs? (For MS SQL, this would be the `IDENTITY` property)

Comment: I work with ORacle datebase.
Id are generated with sequences in the database.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework with a code-first or database-first (designer/EDMX) paradigm?

Comment: I'm using EF with a code first.

Comment: Does your property `NO_SEQ_MDL_DOC` have the `[Key]` attribute/data-annotation?

Comment: Yes it has this attribute.

Comment: Do you have it set up to actually use a separate transaction, or are you only using the `.SaveChanges()` as your transaction scope?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the transaction is completed before checking the PK value.
Also, I would try removing the redundant assignment on your last line: `docCible.NO_SEQ_MDL_DOC = docCible.NO_SEQ_MDL_DOC;`

Example calling transaction.Complete()

```
context.SCR_MDL_DOC.Add(docCible);
context.SaveChanges();

transaction.Complete(); // Call Complete() on TransactionScope object

var id = docCible.NO_SEQ_MDL_DOC; // ID should be available at this point
```

Alternatively, you could use `context.Database` to execute a SQL command to get the next sequence:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select SOME_SEQ.nextval from dual;").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The problem is that at this moment, the transaction is not yet completed...
I have others datas to save depending of the id of this record.
If I complete my transaction, I Can't rollback later if I have a problem on an other table?

Comment: When I try your solution, in my id object, I got a null value.

Comment: Actually, in this case the SQL output parameter may be unnecessary; try this: `var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select SOME_SEQ.nextval from dual;").FirstOrDefault();`